# Can we have the Ubuntu emoticons in the chat room?

Tags: feature-request

Can we have the [Ubuntu emoticons](http://design.canonical.com/2010/10/ubuntu-emoticons/) on the general chat room?

[image: ubuntu-emoticons]

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion this one will be met with why not a userscript instead of an infrastructure change...

Comment: There is historical precedent for this sort of thing: RPG chat has an awesome dice emulator, and Arqade has a game in its chat. I think Super User has a clippy thingy.

Answer (score 2):

Let's not. Please. Personally, I find the colored smileys that so many services insert awful:

1. They break the flow of text.
2. They tend to be larger than normal characters, making the line they are in taller and so inserting spaces between lines.
3. Unnecessary overhead (OK, extremely minor issue).
4. Ugly (very personal choice of course but there you go).

If we're going to add something to chat let's make it useful, something like having code blocks displayed with a different background `like this` so we could easily paste commands in chat. As it stands, we just get a fixed width font, no background and it is easy to get confused.

Comment: Exactly. <filler>

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought would be to just upload individual images from [this lot of reasonably sized set of PNG emoticons](http://design.canonical.com/brand/Examples/Emoticons/Emoticons.tar.gz) - example:

[image]

The problem here is, I think because of the way the chat system works *(I don't often use it, so correct me if I am wrong)*, is that *it uploads a new image each time*. I already have accidentally done two:

[image: smiley1] + [image: smiley2] = :D

So the image servers might just fill up with AskUbuntu smileys [image: uhoh]

I also remember from the million edits of [my post here](https://askubuntu.com/a/401012/178596) pointed me in the direction of this:
 [Do we have a policy on smileys?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172143/do-we-have-a-policy-on-smileys)

Though this will probably be considered differently on chat - and perhaps even Meta...[image: smiley again...]

Comment: We have a shortcut URL that's somewhat configurable at hostmar.co, it's how we do the software icons. While it's not a small URL you could do something like `![](http://hostmar.co/software-small)` in chat. Ideally a userscript that rewrites :) :D :( etc in to an image is the best way to go.